# Exception is Thrown when Opening the Webcam using com.github.sarxos library

Tags: java, webcam, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to detect my webcam using `com.github.sarxos` library. This is the [download link](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/releases/download/webcam-capture-parent-0.3.10/webcam-capture-0.3.10-dist.zip) to the library.
    import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;

```
public class DetectWebcamExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    if (webcam != null) {
        System.out.println("Webcam: " + webcam.getName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No webcam detected");
    }
 }
}
```

But every time I run the program it throws an Exception like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
   at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:97)
   at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:97)
   at webcam.WebCam.main(WebCam.java:12)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
   ... 2 more
Java Result: 1
```

Can you please tell me what is the wrong with the Code or Library?
I have added the Library (*Which I downloaded in the link given above as a .zip file*) to the Library folder in `Netbeans`. Are there any libraries that I should Add???

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the third-party dependencies of the library, in the dl link there should be libs file containing (slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar, bridj-0.6.2.jar), add those .jars into your project and it should work. The exception is simply saying it cannot find the classes, that is needed to run the library as they are contained different .jar file